# Header with logout button in windows phone 7

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, header

I am new to windows phone development.

I need the custom header with Logout button and then use it on every page.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is not a good idea to have a `Logout` button in a header on every page in your app. I would suggest you to use `ApplicationBar` for such purpose and add there an logout `MenuItem`. The main idea is that logout operation is not frequently used, so it is hidden. And add you logout logic to base `PhoneApplicationPage` class or base `ViewModel` class. 
If using an `ApplicationBar` is not suitable for you, you can use `UserControl` and add it to every application page.
Example of header `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp3.LogoutUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="/Images/Header.jpg"/>
            <Button Click="Logout" Content="Logout"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And your main page looks like

```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:PhoneApp3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <userControls:LogoutUserControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="HeaderControl"/>
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```